# Made a small personal WP plugin, it is adding empty lines to PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a small WordPress plugin to do somethings related to my website.

Whenever I activate the plugin, my sitemap stops working because the plugin is adding empty lines to PHP which gives the XML declaration error.

Here is the code of my plugin, can anyone please check the code to see what's causing the issue?

```
         <?php
        /* 
        Plugin Name: Plugin Name
        Plugin URI:  http://www.myname.com
        Version:     0.1
        Author:      My Name
        Author URI:  http://www.myname.com
        */

        /* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */
        //Facebook Pixel Code
        add_action('wp_footer', 'add_fbpixel');
        function add_fbpixel() { ?>
        <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
        <script>
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
        n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
        document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        fbq('init', '21013842347932424383447');
        fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
        <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=210138479383447&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        /></noscript>
        <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
        <?php }

        //Google Anaylytics Code
        add_action('wp_footer', 'add_googleanalytics');
        function add_googleanalytics() { ?>
        <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
          ga('create', 'UA-2423423401-1', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <?php }

        //Admin Page Logo Change
        function my_login_logo() { ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
                    background-image: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/wp-logo.png);
                }
            </style>
        <?php }
        add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
        function my_login_logo_url() {
            return home_url();
        }
        add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );
        function my_login_logo_url_title() {
            return 'Domain';
        }
        add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );

        //Duplicate Meta Description Fix
        if ( ! function_exists( 'fix_duplicate_meta' ) )
        {
            function fix_duplicate_meta( $s )
            {
                global $page;
                $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                ! empty ( $page ) && 1 < $page && $paged = $page;
                $paged > 1 && $s .= ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page: %s' ), $paged );
                return $s;
            }
            add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'fix_duplicate_meta', 100, 1 );
        }
```

Here is a pastebin of the code as well: https://pastebin.com/JmdzVzeZ

Comment: Is the whitespace at the beginning in your code or did you indent it to post here?

Comment: Remove whitespace before <?php tag.

Comment: That's just indentation.

Comment: Even if it's just indentation, if it exists in the original file, then it is a problem. Remove it.